# How to hide component like a button in Form.io

Tags: angular, forms, formio

I am struggling with Formio hiding the button component of my form. I need to hide my submit button in my form. Please help. Thanks in advance

The only thing that I think should work you can see in my code. I have tried putting it to my `renderOptions` as an array as well. Nothing worked yet.

HTML:

```
<div>   
    <formio 
        [form]="structuredForm" 
        [submission]='{"data":formSubmission }'
        [renderOptions]="formioRenderOptions"
        hide-components="['submit', 'submit5']"> 
    </formio> 
</div>
```

My `formioRenderOption` do I need to set the hidden buttons here?

```
this.formioRenderOptions = {
  noAlerts: true,
  language: this.translateService.currentLang.replace('_', '-')
  i18n: '',
  readOnly: true,
};
```

My Formio JSON file with 2 buttons:

```
        {
            "label": "save",
            "action": "event",
            "showValidations": false,
            "event": "saveDraftEvent",
            "theme": "primary",
            "shortcut": "",
            "disableOnInvalid": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": true,
            "alwaysEnabled": false,
            "type": "button",
            "key": "submit4",
            "input": true,
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": "",
                "json": ""
            },
            "customConditional": "",
            "properties": {},
            "tags": [],
            "logic": [],
            "defaultValue": true
        },
        {
            "label": "next",
            "action": "event",
            "showValidations": false,
            "event": "submitApplicationEvent",
            "theme": "primary",
            "shortcut": "",
            "disableOnInvalid": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": true,
            "alwaysEnabled": false,
            "type": "button",
            "key": "submit5",
            "input": true,
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": "",
                "json": ""
            },
```

Right now my form is readOnly, however, the buttons are still visible and not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hidden property of the component that you don't want to show as true.

```
"hidden": true
```

If you want to show or hide the component conditionally based on the value of other components in the form then you can use a conditional property of the component object.

```
"conditional": {
    "show": "",
    "when": "",
    "json": ""
},
```

Here, "show" property will hold either 'true' or 'false', "when" property will hold the condition and "json" property will hold any other json validation code.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hidden property true as already answered here! Or if you want to set the property hidden after your form loads in any certain time you can do this

```
controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
         $scope.component.type='hidden';

    }],
```

and this will change the attribute type to

> form-field-type-hidden